# Elegant way to check for equal values within an array or any given textfile

Tags: bash

Hello i'm fairly new to scripting, and struggling with trying to test/check if 4 lines in a textfile are equal to eachother, and i cannot figure this one out since comparison examples are all with two variables. i've come up with this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#check if mxf videofiles are older than 10 minutes and parse them into tclist.txt
find . -amin +10 |sed "s/^..//" >tclist.txt
#grep timecode and cut : from the output of mxfprobe and place that into variable TC
for z in $(cat tclist.txt); do TC=$(mxfprobe -i "$z" 2>&1 |grep timecode|sed "s/[^0-9]*//"|sed "s/://"|sed "s/://"|sed "s/://")
echo $TC >>offsetcheck.txt
done;
```

The output of offsetcheck.txt then looks like this:

10194013
10194013
10194014
10194014

How can i test if those 4 values are equal to eachother? (in this example two files are drifted one frame)

I've tried to place those values into an array and check them for uniqueness...

```
exec 10<&0
exec < offsetcheck.txt
let count=0
while read LINE; do
     ARRAY[$count]=$LINE
     ((count++))
done
echo ${ARRAY[@]}
exec 0<&10 10<&-
if ($ARRAY !== array_unique($ARRAY))
{
  echo There were duplicate values
}
```

Comment: Note: you can replace `|sed "s/[^0-9]*//"|sed "s/://"|sed "s/://"|sed "s/://"` with `|sed 's/[^0-9]//g'`

Comment: Don't do `for z in $(cat tclist.txt);` Instead do `while read z;do;...done < tclist.txt`

Answer (score 1):

> ... struggling with trying to test/check if 4 lines in a textfile are
>   equal to eachother

You could use `sort` and `wc` to determine the number of unique values in the file.  The following would tell whether the file contains unique values or not:

```
(( $(sort -u offsetcheck.txt | wc -l) == 1 )) && echo "File contains unique values" || echo "File does not contain unique values"
```

---

If you wanted to do the same for an array, you could say:

```
for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do echo "$i" ; done | sort -u | wc -l
```

to get the number of unique values in the array.

If the values in the array are guaranteed not to have any space, then saying:

```
echo "${ARRAY[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | wc -l
```

would suffice.  (But note the *if* above.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the whole process can be reduced to

```
n=$(
    find . -amin +10 | 
    sed "s/^..//" | 
    xargs -I FILE mxfprobe -i "FILE" 2>&1 |
    grep -h timecode | 
    sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | 
    sort -u | 
    wc -l
)
```

Then check if n == 1